# Scalable solution for geocoding on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, geocoding, google-calendar-api

I'm working on an iOS app that pulls events from Google Calendar and subsequently generates pins on a map for each event (based on what the event creator fills in for "Location"). The user can select a date range (today, this week, this month, etc.) and see all the events taking place near them over that period.

**Problem 1:** The app is for my local university, so a majority of the locations will be buildings on campus. These buildings have inconsistent addresses that are often difficult to find, so it would be good if the location "Foo Hall" would result in a pin on that building. Google Maps is capable of doing this, however Apple Maps has no knowledge of the buildings on my school campus.

**Problem 2:** In an ideal situation, thousands of students would be using this app. Each time they open the app, they could be viewing dozens of pins. Therefore, I'm worried that I may be pushing the limits imposed by Google's geocoding API (definitely the 2500 request limit, and maybe even the 100,000 request limit for the Business API).

**So my question is...** what would be the best solution for these two problems? Should I create a local database for building names and map them to coordinates? Or is there a way I can overcome the limitations of Google's Geocoding API? Is there a better solution I'm not thinking of?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use latitude and longitude coordinates for the buildings and allow for people to add locations to the database if they are meeting somewhere that you have not added already.  This way, the pins will drop in the center of the building if you want them to, because you are not relying on an address or on looking up a building name.  You simply know that "Foo Hall" is at X latt. and Y long.  And if someone selects "Foo Hall" or sees an event at "Foo Hall" there is a perfectly placed pin right in the middle of it on the map.  I don't think you need to worry as much about the geocoding API if you are using hardcoded locations for the buildings either, because you won't have to be polling Google to get the building locations.

I would also use some sort of server to store the building locations so they can be updated or added to, either by you or by the users.

That's how I would handle it, good luck!